# Кэш память потоков и оперативная память

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть следующий код, поток просто добавляет числа по возрастанию в список:

```
 List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

    ListThread listThread1 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread2 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread3 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread4 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread5 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread6 = new ListThread(integers);
    ListThread listThread7 = new ListThread(integers);

    listThread1.start();
    listThread2.start();
    listThread3.start();
    listThread4.start();
    listThread5.start();
    listThread6.start();
    listThread7.start();

    listThread1.join();
    listThread2.join();
    listThread3.join();
    listThread4.join();
    listThread5.join();
    listThread6.join();
    listThread7.join();
    
    System.out.println(integers);
```

Выводится следующая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 171 out of bounds for length 163
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:455)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
```

Вопрос:
как я понял, у каждого потока свой кэш и у каждого в кэше хранится "своя версия" полей `integers`, а сам список `integers` хранится в оперативной памяти. Как тогда происходит это взаимодействие информации из кэша и информации из  оперативной памяти, ведь если поток хочет положить какой-то элемент за пределы массива, то значит в кэше этого потока это массив уже увеличен. И как формируется список в нашей оперативной памяти, если в кэшах есть множество его вариантов, какой вариант попадает в оперативную память?

```
public class ListThread extends Thread {

private final List<Integer> list;

public ListThread(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут дело в том, что потоки при выполнении своей работы конкурируют между собой, а коллекция `ArrayList`, как правильно заметили в другом ответе, не является потокобезопасной. Так выглядит метод `add()` класса `ArrayList`, который вы используете для добавления элементов:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}
```

а так выглядит приватный метод `add()`, на который он опирается:

```
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

Потоки конкуррентно выполняют вызов публичного метода `add()`, и при такой их работе могут быть разные "неожиданные" эффекты. Может быть брошено исключение, а может быть и не брошено, зато в окончательном списке окажутся далеко не все элементы.

Разберём случай с исключением. Все потоки одновременно вызывают `add()`, который в свою очередь вызывает приватный `add()`, в котором блок `if` не выполняется (поначалу `size` меньше размера массива), элемент добавляется и переменная `size` наращивается. Может произойти так, что все потоки одновременно нарастят `size` таким образом, что она перескочит через `elementData.length`, превысив фактический размер массива. И при следующем вызове приватного метода `add()` блок `if` всё так же не выполнится, соответственно, массив не расширится, соответственно, будем пытаться добавить элемент по индексу, превышающему размер массива, отсюда и исключение.

Но есть и другая упомянутая выше ситуация. Потоки, вызывая `add()` одновременно и не ожидая друг друга, зачастую будут вызывать его с одинаковым `size`, так как за счёт того, что не все `add()`-ы отработали, она не нарастится нужное количество раз. Отсюда получаем добавление на одинаковые позиции и "неполноценный" окончательный список в том случае, если программа отработает и исключение не будет брошено.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` просто не потокобезопасный объект. Используйте потокобезопасные коллекции для работы со списком из нескольких потоков, варианты есть например [на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444005/how-do-i-make-my-arraylist-thread-safe-another-approach-to-problem-in-java).

Например, можно использовать [Collections.synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Comment: Спасибо, но меня больше интересует именно вопрос, связанный с взаимодействием кэша и памяти

Comment: @stepanevgen2013 Ну это мягко говоря довольно широкая тема. Почитайте например базовые вещи https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8